# Load up existing Chrome user profile & data with chromedp

Tags: google-chrome, go, chromedp

When I load up a chromedp context I want it to use my default Chrome session. Keeping all session data and things. So when I load up Dropbox, Discord, Twitter, YouTube... etc I should already logged in and can readily interact with them through chromedp.

I understand there may be security concerns so this action may be impossible. I am only building this tool for personal use and to automate some generic web tasks. I could of course copy all my cookies, auth headers  over to the program or physically add logging in using given credentials but it would be easier if I could just specify one flag to deal with using existing detail. I am almost certain that this functionality is in puppeteer?

I have tried adding `` chromedp.Flag("profile-directory", `"Default"`) ``. But it produces a blank window (see below) rather than doing following any Actions. Removing this line will make it function as expected but in an anonymous session.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i set these flags
then a new profile was created
then i synced it with my google account
and every time i run chromedp with `sudo`
it syncs with my account
Edit: You can set `UserDataDir` in a non hidden folder
 (e.g. `/home/user/Profile 1/`)
and you won't need to use `subo`

`chromedp.Flag("profile-directory","Profile 1"),
chromedp.UserDataDir("/home/user/.config/chromium/Profile 1"),
chromedp.Flag("disable-sync", false),`